# How to zoom on marker click event in Mapbox Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I want to zoom on a marker when it is clicked. I am using Mapbox and leaflet.

I tried:

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
    map.setView([e.lat, e.lng], 12);
});
```

But it gives me some kind of error:

> TypeError: t is null

I even tried:

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
    map.fitBounds(marker.getBounds());
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the latitude and longitude of the event, you must use e.latlng: [latlng reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-latlng). Use this:

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
    map.setView(e.latlng, 13);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
    map.setView([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], 12);
});
```